# blender video input

Tags: video, error, 3d-printing

I've been trying to input a video in a cubes on blender 3d software, somehow it seems right way but never worked out for me. please check the image below, i have few evidences for it.

[image: this is a screen shot of blender please check this out and reply me the detail of the error]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Apart from what @L0Lock suggests in his answer - the _Image Texture_ which provides the video to be displayed uses the UV map as default texture ccordinates. Is the screen correctly UV unwrapped to show the video? Just because the name of the object "Cylinder" which has this material looks to me as if this was originally a mesh primitive cylinder, which I doubt comes with a great UV map for a TV screen by default.

Answer (score 4):

Set your viewport to either material or rendered shading:

[image]

Or, if you want to keep the solid shading you are in, you need to set its color option to *Texture*. You will find viewport shading options in the popover just on their right:

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying to my message, i tried to solve this problem following the steps you showed, but when i clicked on "Viewport Shading," the screen didn't display the same image as the second one you posted.

Comment: each viewport shading have its own settings. These are the ones for Solid shading, like the one you used when you made your screenshot.